# Use mapply and keep the structure of the original list

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a list "temp" which is equal to

```
[[1]]
[1] 8 0 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 4 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 5 0
```

and a vector `vec = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`. I want to get a list
with the same structure as "temp" which will contain the maximum
for each element between temp an vec. The desired new list will be equal to

```
[[1]]
[1] 8 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

If I execute

`mapply(max, temp, vec)`

I get

```
8 6 5 8 6 6 8 8 9
```

which is the wrong result and the wrong structure.

And if I execute

```
lapply(temp, function(x) mapply(max, unlist(temp), vec))
```

I get the following

```
[[1]]
[1] 8 2 3 6 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 8 2 3 6 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 8 2 3 6 5 6 7 8 9
```

This is in a way the correct result with the wrong structure.
Is there a vectorized way to get the desired effect? It is important
for this to run very fast...

Thank you!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the maximum for each element between temp and vec"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp <- list(c(8,0,3),c(6,4,0),c(0,5,0))
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Using the dimensions of the `temp` list, you can split and compare:

```
Map(pmax, temp, split(vec, rep(seq_along(temp),sapply(temp,length))))
```

...or compare and split:

```
split( pmax(unlist(temp),vec), rep(seq_along(temp),sapply(temp,length)) )
```

..or just for showing that there's a million ways to do everything:

```
split(sweep(do.call(rbind,temp),2:1,vec,FUN="pmax"),1:length(temp))
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 8 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 6 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: Splitting the result of mapply gives the wrong list names, but otherwise the correct structure: `split(mapply(max, unlist(temp), vec), rep(seq_along(temp),sapply(temp,length)))`

Comment: is there a way to use something else than split? e.g. to calculate the mean of a vector 1:12 by 4 to get (2.5, 6.5, 10.5) without using split... something faster..

Comment: @conighion - something like `x <- 1:12; colMeans(matrix(x,nrow=4))` perhaps?